# Oracle conversion of UNIX timestamp to timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

Trying to convert UNIX timestamp to Oracle timestamp with timezone.
Expecting to see different output, however datetime part is the same.

What is wring ?

```
select (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1204104116656/1000,'second')) at time zone tz_offset('EST') from dual;
```

Output: 27-FEB-08 **09.21.56**.656000000 AM **-05:00**

```
select (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1204104116656/1000,'second')) at time zone tz_offset('PST') from dual;
```

Output: 27-FEB-08 **09.21.56**.656000000 AM **-07:00**

How come date / time part is the same? Does not Oracle do adjustment ?

Answer (score 8):

Unix timestamp is from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. When you just do `timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'` Oracle takes your local time zone!

You have to do it like this:

```
(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' +     
    numtodsinterval(1204104116656/1000,'second')) AT time zone tz_offset('PST');
```